# Flutter: Background image moves and overlaps with other elements when I resize my browser screen

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am very new to flutter and have a very basic query:
I have set a background image in my website that I am building using flutter. I am testing the output on chrome browser. When I resize the browser screen to a smaller size the background image overlaps with other elements on the page.

1. How do I fix the position of the image irrespective of the screen size(make the website scrollable)?
2. Can I programmatically remove the image if the screen size falls below a certain dimension?

This is how my code looks right now:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const String _bgImagePath='assets/images/temp.jpeg';

    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: size.height,
            width: size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(_bgImagePath),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  scale: 2.1
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: size.height,
            width: size.width,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                CustomAppBar(),
                Spacer(),
                Body(),
                Spacer(
                  flex: 2,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I added margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 500) to the container in which the image BoxDecoration is defined => This shrinks and makes the image disappear when I shrink my browser screen size to its smallest dimension. This is solving the query I have asked above. However, I would still want to know if this is the right way to accomplish this or there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
fit: BoxFit.cover,
```

to your DecorationImage. It tells Flutter that the image should always cover the entire container regardless of whether the container is bigger or smaller than the image dimensions.

Comment: This makes sense Andrei. My bad. Thanks a lot for the direction.

Comment: I'm glad I cloud help! Please accept the answer so that this question does not hang in unanswered queue.